# cpu load and django application that makes long-response-time requests to external API

Tags: django, web-applications, wsgi, tornado

I'm developing a web application in python for which each user request makes an API call to an external service and takes about **20 seconds** to receive response. As a result, in the event of several concurrent requests being made, the CPU load goes crazy (>95%) with several idle processes.

The server consists of a 1.6 GHz dual core Atom 330 with 2GB RAM.

The web app is developed in python which is served through Apache with mod_wsgi

> My question is the following. Will a non-blocking webserver such as Tornado improve CPU load and thus handle more concurrent users (I'm also interested why) ? Can you suggest any other scalable solution ?

Answer (score 1):

This really doesn't have anything to do with blocking; it does, but it doesn't. The 20 sec request is blocking one thread, so another has be utilized for the next request. Whereas with quick requests, the threads basically round-robin.

However, this really shouldn't be spiking your CPU output. Webservers have an upward limit of "workers" that get spawned and when they're all tied up, they're all tied up. It won't extend past the limit, so unless you've set or the default setting is higher than the box you have is capable of running, it shouldn't push your CPU that high.

Regardless, all that is merely informational, and doesn't really solve your problem. With such a long running request though, you should be offloading this from your webserver as quick as possible. The webserver should merely hand off the request to another process that can asyncronously handle it and then employ polling to notify the client when the response is ready. Node.js is used a lot in similar scenarios, but I really don't have enough experience with it to give you any real guidance beyond that.

Comment: Isn't that what tornado does? I think it uses epoll, like node.js.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using message queues to offload tasks so that your user requests are not blocked.

You could look into python libs kombu and celery to handle messages and tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely using prefork MPM with Apache and mod_wsgi embedded mode. This is a bad combination by default because Apache is setup for PHP and not fat Python web applications. Read:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/load-spikes-and-excessive-memory-usage.html

which explains this exact sort of issue.

Use mod_wsgi daemon mode at the minimum, and preferably also change to worker MPM for Apache.